# Timezone differences resulting in an incorrect time remaining when using Laravel and javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, time, timezone, php-carbon

I'm trying to get the remaining time in a booking page. I'm giving javascript the date and exact starting time of a booking as follows :

```
if (Auth()->user()->role == 1) { //this is the owner of the time slot that was selected. So it makes sense not to set a time zone for him.
    $dateTime = Carbon::parse($dateTime . ' ' . $book->from);
} else { //this is a normal user
    $dateTime = Carbon::parse($dateTime . ' ' . $book->from)->setTimezone(Auth()->user()->time_zone);
}
```

And the javascript function handles it as follows :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1)
    $('.date').datepicker({minDate: tomorrow, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});

    currentDate = new Date();
    currentDateNextFiveDays =  currentDate;
    remainingTime =  new Date(currentDateNextFiveDays) - new Date(currentDate);
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("{{$dateTime}}");
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        // Get today's date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        // days = days * 24;
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        // hours = hours + days;
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
        if(-3000 < distance && distance < -1000) {
            location.reload();
        }
        if(distance > 0) {
            if(days > 0) {
                $('.remaining-time').text(days + " " + "@lang('profile.lang_day')");
            }
            else {
                $('.remaining-time').text(hours + " " + "@lang('profile.lang_hour')" + " " + minutes + " " + "@lang('profile.lang_minutes')" + " " + seconds + " " + "@lang('profile.lang_second')");
            }
        }
        else {
            $('.remaining-time-button').hide();
        }
    }, 1000);
});

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}
```

The code works perfectly fine but whenever I use two browsers from different countries, it will give different results. (Plus 3 hours, plus 10 hours.. depending on the time zones)

The server time zone is located in Asia/Riyadh. And I do store the user's time zone each time they login but I'm not sure how is that going to help me in this case. I show the date and times correctly without any problem (In relative to the timezone) but the remaining time is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The comment assertion is not accurate. Doing differently for users in the same or other timezone is not relevant. You should give to JS the ISO string with GMT timezone (that's done automatically if you send it through a JSON response. You will get a string like `2020-06-30T19:49:03.123Z` where `Z` means `GMT`.

So use:

```
 $dateTime = Carbon::parse($dateTime . ' ' . $book->from)->toJSON();
```

For every users. So `new Date("{{$dateTime}}");` will perfectly understand it's a GMT date and it will convert it. So if your JS script doesn't mess up the timezone, it will be the same duration everywhere.